# bypass read command in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script like this:

```
#some commands
#.....
read answer
#....
#Other commands
```

the answer should be `yes` or `no`.

I want to run the script and bypass reading `answer` giving it the value `yes`. But I can't edit the script's code.

Is there anyway to do that using parameters or some bash tools??

Comment: Is that read the only input required by the script? In that case a simple `echo "yes" | ./script.sh` would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pipe a 'yes' into the standard input of your script:

```
echo yes | your_bash_script
```

Comment: Yes!, that's it. thank you very much. I don't know how I didn't think about that, so close!